# How to run c# code in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, development

I need to run some code when a user login in SharePoint. I have the following code

```
using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://mySite/sites/test"))
        {
            SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb();
            SPFolder oFolder = oWebsite.RootFolder;

            string groupName = "ES HR";
            var spGroup = oWebsite.Groups[groupName];
            isMember = oWebsite.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(spGroup.ID);


            oFolder.WelcomePage = "SitePages/General/Dashboard.aspx";
            oFolder.Update();
            oWebsite.Dispose();
        }
```

First I want to know if current user is in `ES HR` group i want to change the `homepage` and my code is working for this requirement.

But where should I put this code? Do I have to put it in a feature, or do I have to put it elsewhere.

I was thinking to put my code when a user login in sharepoint

Comment: Are you working on `SharePoint Online` or `SharePoint On-Premises` ?

Comment: SharePoint On-Premises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a visual web part and put following code in `.cs` file of your webpart. Here I have also modified your code.

The line `oFolder.WelcomePage = "SitePages/General/Dashboard.aspx";` will set the welcome page for all users of the site therefore instead of setting Welcome page based on current user group, you should redirect user to the specific page if he/she is in a particular group.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://mySite/sites/test"))
        {
            SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb();
            SPFolder oFolder = oWebsite.RootFolder;

            string groupName = "ES HR";
            var spGroup = oWebsite.Groups[groupName];
            if (oWebsite.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(spGroup.ID))
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/SitePages/General/Dashboard.aspx");
            }
            oWebsite.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Now insert this web part into your current welcome page.

Comment: `Response` does not exist in my client context

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework client object model (CSOM) or Server Side Object Model Code in your code?? because I have given SSOM code in my answer.

Comment: I think i am using ssom

Comment: use sputility.redirect() for redirection. SPUtility.Redirect("http://www.cnn.com", SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEndResponse | SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, HttpContext.Current);
You could probably omit 'SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEndResponse'.                                                        or HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect() .

Comment: If you are using SSOM then `Response` object should be available via `System.Web.UI` namespace. Include it your `.cs` file. I have tried this code and its working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on SharePoint on-prem you can create a user control add your code to it and add it to your custom master page, so when  a user will login to SharePoint this code will execute.

Comment: How can I add c# code into masterpage?

Comment: You need to create a User Control and then add that control into the master page. http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2011/10/sharepoint-2010-add-user-control-to.html